# Solving the PDE $\partial_t u = \partial_x (u^2 \partial_xu)$

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

I'm trying to use Mathematica to solve the following equation $$\partial_t u = \partial_x (u^2 \partial_xu)$$ with $$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$$ and $$u_0(x)=\sin(\pi x)$$ in order to check a numerical method I developed with Python. What I obtain at **time $t=1$** with Python is the following one:

[image]

I want to use Mathematica to see whether its solution is the same I obtain or not, but since I'm not familiar, I can't do that and I need a check.

Any confirm or check is highly appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
   D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t]^2 D[u[x, t], x], x],
   u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == Sin[Pi x]}
  , u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Then

```
Plot[sol[x, t] /. t -> Range[0, 5]/5 // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Range[0, 5]/5, PlotStyle -> ColorData[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try now, but I can't understand (from your graph), what is the colour that corresponds to $t=1$.

Comment: I just reimplemented everything with finite differences (following this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805692/finite-difference-non-linear-diffusion-coefficient), and I find the same solution you wrote for different times! Still don't know what's wrong with my FEM, but thanks again!